# no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('22TP2TT490S ')

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services

Below is Rest Controller class, which is post request

```
@PostMapping(value = "/details")
public SubSeriesDetailsRequest getGlobalSearchProductDetails(@RequestBody List<SubSeriesCodesRequest> codes,
        @QueryParam("contextString") String contextString) {

    LOGGER.info("Inside post request " + codes);

    String url = "http://www.example.com/details";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    // SubSeriesDetailsRequest detailsRequest = new SubSeriesDetailsRequest();

    SubSeriesDetailsRequest response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, SubSeriesDetailsRequest.class);
    return response;

}
```

my dto class

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class SubSeriesCodesRequest implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6880035785505252493L;
private List<String> codes;

public SubSeriesCodesRequest(List<String> codes) {
    super();
    this.codes = codes;
}

@JsonCreator
public SubSeriesCodesRequest() {

}

public List<String> getCodes() {
    return codes;
}

public void setCodes(List<String> codes) {
    this.codes = codes;
}
```

need to implement post request like this below
[image]

Comment: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.ims.dto.SubSeriesCodesRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('22TP2TT490S'); nested exception is .MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.ims.dto.SubSeriesCodesRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('22TP2TT490S')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])]

Answer (score 0):

Your request does not match the expected model. You are saying you expect a `List` of `SubSeriesCodesRequest` and you are sending an array of strings.

Your current model seems to be like this example:

```
[
    {
        "codes": [
            "Code 1",
            "Code 2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Try changing your method to something like this `public SubSeriesDetailsRequest getGlobalSearchProductDetails(@RequestBody SubSeriesCodesRequest request,` and it should work ok.

Comment: Hi Lucas JC,  I have changed like above ,Can you please see my error ,Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.ims.ldto.SubSeriesCodesRequest` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.ims.dto.SubSeriesCodesRequest` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
Kindly help me ,I am really not understanding this

Comment: Please post a more complete stacktrace. Also, you should inspect what you are sending as a json payload (Are testing directly from that swagger ui you showed? Are you using postman?)